# Ridge Regression: Scikit-learn vs. direct calculation does not match for alpha > 0

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

In Ridge Regression, we are solving `Ax=b` with `L2` Regularization. The direct calculation is given by:

> x = (A<sup>T</sup>A + alpha * I)<sup>-1</sup>A<sup>T</sup>b

I have looked at the scikit-learn code and they do implement the same calculation. But, I can't seem to get the same results for `alpha > 0`

The minimal code to reproduce this.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.asmatrix(np.c_[np.ones((10,1)),np.random.rand(10,3)])
b = np.asmatrix(np.random.rand(10,1))
I = np.identity(A.shape[1])
alpha = 1
x = np.linalg.inv(A.T*A + alpha * I)*A.T*b
print(x.T)
>>> [[ 0.37371021  0.19558433  0.06065241  0.17030177]]

from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
model = Ridge(alpha = alpha).fit(A[:,1:],b)
print(np.c_[model.intercept_, model.coef_])
>>> [[ 0.61241566  0.02727579 -0.06363385  0.05303027]]
```

Any suggestions on what I can do to resolve this discrepancy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This modification seems to yield the same result for the direct version and the numpy version:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.asmatrix(np.random.rand(10,3))
b = np.asmatrix(np.random.rand(10,1))
I = np.identity(A.shape[1])
alpha = 1
x = np.linalg.inv(A.T*A + alpha * I)*A.T*b
print (x.T)


from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
model = Ridge(alpha = alpha, tol=0.1, fit_intercept=False).fit(A ,b)

print model.coef_
print model.intercept_
```

It seems the main reason for the difference is  the class `Ridge` has the parameter `fit_intercept=True` (by inheritance from class `_BaseRidge`) ([source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/linear_model/ridge.py#L601))

This is applying a data centering procedure before passing the matrices to the `_solve_cholesky` function.

Here's the line in ridge.py that does it

```
        X, y, X_mean, y_mean, X_std = self._center_data(
        X, y, self.fit_intercept, self.normalize, self.copy_X,
        sample_weight=sample_weight)
```

Also, it seems you were trying to implicitly account for the intercept by adding the column of 1's. As you see, this is not necessary if you specify `fit_intercept=False`

Appendix: Does the Ridge class actually implement the direct formula?

It depends on the choice of the `solver`parameter.

Effectively, if you do not specify the `solver`parameter in `Ridge`, it takes by default `solver='auto'` (which internally resorts to `solver='cholesky'`). This should be equivalent to the direct computation.

Rigorously, `_solve_cholesky` uses `numpy.linalg.solve` instead of `numpy.inv`. But it can be easily checked that

```
np.linalg.solve(A.T*A + alpha * I, A.T*b)
```

yields the same as

```
np.linalg.inv(A.T*A + alpha * I)*A.T*b
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. This does resolve for the `fit_intercept = False`. However, in my example I do want the `intercept` and hence I do add the column of 1's to my `A` matrix in the direct calculation. I drop the 1's column when I pass to the `Ridge` by using `A[:,1:]`. So even if I run the `model = Ridge(alpha = alpha, normalize = False, fit_intercept = True, solver = "cholesky").fit(A[:,1:],b)` - I am not able to get the same result. Any clarification when you want `fit_intercept = True`?

Comment: I believe you can still keep the line `A = np.asmatrix(np.c_[np.ones((10,1)),np.random.rand(10,3)])`and set `fit_intercept=False`. Shouldn't the first coeffcient then be the intercept?

Comment: Yes - That does it! Should have thought about it. Still wondering why `normalize = False, fit_intercept=True` does not do the same. Thanks for all your help.